# Получение тела запроса в nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

у меня есть функция на сайте, которая отправляет запрос на мой сервер:

```
search(str) {
            var requestUrlSearch = '';
            var requestOptions = {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                    "cache-control": "no-cache"
                },
                body: {
                 'size': '7',
                 'filter[FETI]': 'lot_year_date:[* TO NOW/YEAR-25YEARS],buy_it_now_code:B1',
                 'filter[MAKE]': 'lot_make_desc:"BMW"'
                }
            };

            return fetch(requestUrlSearch, requestOptions);
        },
```

На моём сервере я принимаю её таким кодом(и делаю запрос к еще одному серверу, но это не важно в данном вопросе):

```
router.post('/Search', function(req, res, next) {

    var options = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: '',
        headers: {
            "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            'cache-control': 'no-cache'
        },
        form: req.body
    };
    console.log(req.body);
    request(options, function(error, response, body) {
        if (error) throw new Error(error);
        res.send(body);
    });
});
```

А вот что важно: `console.log(req.body);` выводит просто `{}`. Что я делаю не так? Как мне получить доступ к данным которые находятся в `requestOptions.body` из функции `search`(первый кусок кода) на своём сервере(второй кусок кода)? Спасибо

**UPD**:
из файла `app.js`:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

**UPD#2:** подсказали использовать https://github.com/axios/axios вместо fetch на клиенте, сильно помогло. надеюсь тому, кто нагуглит этот вопрос это тоже поможет.

Comment: bodyParser стоит?

Comment: да, детали обновил в вопросе

Comment: тестабл репо есть?

Comment: не уверен, что это такое и где посмотреть?

Comment: репозиторий тестовый чтобы я мог посмотреть

Comment: нет, нету, и нету возможности предоставить его. возможно обойтись без него? спасибо

Comment: попробуй вывести res в консоль. Там есть циркулярки, так что лучше в браузере посмотреть что там появляется

Comment: а и вообще разве body вместо form отправлять когда urlencoded. Вроде form на клиенте надо

Comment: по-моему я form отправлял

Comment: form: req.form отдает undefined в консоль

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68608/discussion-between-j-doe-and-herrgott).

Comment: попробуй body на клиенте в JSON.stringify обернуть